# How does graphql apollo server uses memcached as a cache system?

Tags: express, graphql, memcached, apollo-server

Following apollo documentation, I'm unable to get data from memcached with telnet commands. It seems like the data is cached because when I resend the same request the datasource doesn't call the APIs.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  cache: new MemcachedCache(
    '127.0.0.1:11211',
    { retries: 10, retry: 10000 }, // Options
  ),
  dataSources: () => ({
    moviesAPI: new MoviesAPI(),
  }),
});
```

I tried a manual implementation of memcached inside a dummy project and I was able to set/get data in the telnet interface.

Is the memcached queried by graphql or do we need to do it manually in the resolvers ?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

The option to pass a cache into ApolloServer's initialization is optionl. With that being said , the cache highly downsized the speed of your database fetches.You have to pass the given cache in the initialization of any dataSource class, like this:

```
class DogCustomDataSource extends CustomDataSource{
   constructor(models){ 
      ....
      }
   initialize({context,cache}){
   this.context=context
   this.cache=cache
     }
   }
```

Yes, you are right , subsequently, you have to set and delete objects to the cache in the methods of your dataSource, like this:

```
async get(id,{ttlInSeconds}={}){
  .....
  await this.cache.set("yourKey","yourValue",{ttl:ttlInSeconds})
  //or
  await this.cache.del("yourKey")
  .....
}
```